# Fit graphic frame to content InDesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm trying to create a script for InDesign that forces all graphic frames (rectangles) to fit to content. I am using this with XML import and some graphics–particularly in tables–come in with frames smaller than the graphic. We don't want the graphics cropped and we don't want them scaled to a smaller size, so we want to run a script that finds all graphic objects and then forces the frame to fit to the graphic. I found the following string which *should* work, but I can't get it to work for me.

```
app.activeDocument.rectangles.everyItem().fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
```

I created a really simple function with this code, but it doesn't actually do anything. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but my JavaScript experience is pretty limited. Here's my simple function:

```
function fitToFrame(){
    app.activeDocument.rectangles.everyItem().fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
}
```

I also tried treating it like an array, but this doesn't do anything either.

```
function fitToFrame(){
    var doc=app.activeDocument;
    app.findObjectPreferences = null;
    var obj = new Array(doc.rectangles.everyItem());
    for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
        obj[i].fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
    }
 }
```

I tried a different approach to find and identify the objects, but this still doesn't work, and I'm stuck.

```
function fitToFrame(){
    var doc=app.activeDocument;
    app.findObjectPreferences = null;
    var obj = doc.findObject();
    for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
        if (obj[i] instanceof Rectangle){
            obj[i].fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
        }
    }
 }
```

What am I missing? I appreciate any suggestions!

**UPDATE**
I did discover that when I run the last function listed above, *something* happens because it changes my Undo menu in the UI to "Undo Set Frame Fitting Options," but nothing actually changes in the document, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: I found that applying something to everyItem() quite often does not work. Try to loop through the collection and apply one at a time. fit method does work on the rectangle. Also make sure it is applied after you place the graphic

Comment: @NicolaiKant That's what I'm trying to do in my last two versions of the function above, but they don't do anything either. If everyItem() is sketchy, then my last function _should_ work, but it doesn't do anything. I've tested this loop, and I know it is recognizing Rectangle objects, so obj[1] should be recognized as a rectangle and work with fit(), but it doesn't do anything. Incidentally, I use a copy of this same loop to apply specific styles to graphics, and it works without any problem, so I feel like I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: I've had issues with the fit method before and remember that I also did not succeed in getting it to work in a script of mine. I eventually ended up by resizing the boxes via their geometricBounds property (i.e. having my script calculate the size needed for each box and then fitting the geometric bounds to that).

Comment: @mdomino That sounds like a good idea, but I'm not experienced enough to know how to do that. I tried using resolve to get the top left and bottom right anchors and then using reframe (based on the reframing example I found in the scripting API documentation), but it doesn't appear to do anything. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, the fit method for rectangle object works, I used it quite a lot. The problem is in referencing your rectangles and it must be something in the code what we do not see. Try to run this as a separate script:

```
 var obj = app.activeDocument.rectangles;
    
    for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
        obj[i].fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
    }
```